# How to navigate between fragments inflated in a Compose view?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I'm rewriting an Android app with Compose, and everything is going welL.
However in my app, I have a Debug screen which is linked to some Fragments for debugging. And sadly, to use Compose Navigation, all your components have to be Composables...
I can't rewrite these Fragments in Compose for now, so I'm using wrappers screens like that :

```
@Composable
fun DeviceInfoScreen(navController : NavController, fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.debug_title))
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {navController.navigateUp()}) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "backIcon")
                    }
                },
                backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.primary),
                contentColor = Color.White,
                elevation = 77.dp)
        },
        content = {
            Surface(color = colorResource(id = R.color.background), modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
                AndroidViewBinding(FragmentDeviceInfoContainerBinding::inflate) {
                    val myFragment = fragmentDeviceInfoWrapper.getFragment<MyDeviceInfoFragment>()
                }
            }
        })
}
```

And my layout is like that :

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentDeviceInfoWrapper"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:name="com.mypackage.MyDeviceInfoFragment">

</androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
```

So my Fragment is correctly loaded, but this fragment can't navigate to multiple other Fragments, that could also navigate to other Fragments after...
Is there a proper way to give a NavController, or maybe a new Activity outside of Compose so these Fragments can be linked together and be independent? Or anything that allows navigation between fragments, while still coming from a Composable.

I tried something like editing the code in the Fragments and use a transaction like that :

```
childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentDeviceInfoWrapper, SecondFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
```

But I got a crash :
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a031d (com.mypackage:id/fragmentDeviceInfoWrapper) for fragment SecondFragment{e343337}`

I'm out of ideas for now, and I don't think I found something similar elsewhere, so I hope you could help me !
Thanks

Comment: Since there's no reference to the NavController, you probably should navigate via deep links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use simple `<fragment>` tag instead of `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`